# Google Column chart mysql php is not display

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-visualization

As I have written some of Javascript and MySQL for populate dynamic data for google chart, I have got few chart working but one chart is baffled me, I knew it should be working but I feel that I'm missing something, as it doesn't show at all.

error code displayed

> Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: Amazon is not defined
>       at columnCharttotal (Dashboard.php:144)
>       at

Here is Javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //begin columns chart 
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(columnCharttotal);
    function columnCharttotal() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
            ["marketplace_name", "total_amount", {role: "style"}],
<?php
while (($rowResult = mysqli_fetch_array($totalresultchart, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) != NULL) {
    ?>
                [ <?php echo $rowResult["marketplace_name"]; ?>, <?php echo $rowResult["total_amount"]; ?>, "blue"]
    <?php
}
mysqli_free_result($totalresultchart);
?>
        ]);

        var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
        view.setColumns([0, 1,
            {calc: "stringify",
                sourceColumn: 1,
                type: "string",
                role: "annotation"},
            2]);

        var options = {
            title: "Total of all Europe sold",
            height: 400,
            bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
            legend: {position: "none"},
        };
        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
        chart.draw(view, options);
    }
    //end of column chart
</script>
```

here is an HTML code

```
    <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div id="columnchart_values" style="width:100%"></div>
        <br>
    </div>
```

As Chrome Developer tools displayed show data on console

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this line;

`[ <?php echo $rowResult["marketplace_name"]; ?>, <?php echo $rowResult["total_amount"]; ?>, "blue"]`

Its outputting
`[ Amazon.co.uk , 1231231, "Blue" ]`

When it should output:
`[ "Amazon.co.uk" , 1231231, "Blue" ]`

Therefore; change the line too:

`[ "<?php echo $rowResult["marketplace_name"]; ?>", <?php echo $rowResult["total_amount"]; ?>, "blue"]`

Comment: ah, i just knew it, as there is something missing. thank for tip. as i got it working.